# How can I save a drag and dropped image to the server?

Tags: javascript, image, save

First of all, background.
Everything is behind a corporate firewall, so there is no showing a live version or accessing nifty tools like nodeJS or many libraries.

I have HTML, php 5, javascript, and jquery1.9.

I have an web window with a bunch of data.  I want to allow users to be able to drop a picture called a sleuth image into a box, show that box, and save that image in a special location on my server.  The sleuth image is a dynamically generated graph on a different internal server that I have no privileges whatsoever on (another department).  While it could be named anything, I want to save it with a specific name so it displays properly later when the web window for this data is reloaded.

I have this javascript function which allows them to drop an image and displays it.  I just need it to save the image to a .png.

```js
 function drop_handler(event) {
 // this is part of the ability to drag sleuth images onto the OOC
 // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  event.preventDefault();
   var items = event.dataTransfer.items;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   var item = items[i];
   if (item.kind === 'string') {
    item.getAsString(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("sleuth").innerHTML = data;
    });
   }
  } 
 }
```

I need to save the img src that show up in the variable "data" AS "sleuthImg.png"

Yes, I know I need to add validation.  First, I need this part to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need an endpoint on the server that can accept files and store them. Assuming you have that part already, then:

Get the file from the `dataTransfer` object
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files

Then create a new `FormData` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileFromDataTransfer);
formData.append('mime_type', fileFromDataTransfer.type);
```

(where `'file'` is the name of the post parameter that your server is expecting. `'mime_type'` is another form data parameter included as an example)

Then, using the request-making library of your choosing, make a POST request with the form data.

```
post('your/upload/endpoint', formData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  While this is sound advice, it doesn't solve my particular problem due to further complications. I will check it off as solved and approach this problem from another angle.